# routing aliases in micro phalconphp

Tags: phalcon, phalcon-routing

I'm building an api using the micro framework.

I have the following routes:

```
/users/{user_id}
/users/{user_id}/friends
/users/{user_id}/pictures
```

Whats the cleanest way to create the following aliases?

```
/me
/me/friends
/me/pictures
```

Answer (score 1):

Phalcon router supports regular expressions, but they are slightly limited, so I'm not 100% certain this would work. Also the way routing works for micro apps might differ, but you can try using the regular expression like this. Make sure `$userId` defaults to `null` – if it's null, then you know that it's the current user.

```
$app->get('(?:/users/(\\w+)|/me)', function($userId = null){});
```

If this doesn't work then taking out the handler into a non-anonymous function and specifying two routes would be the only way. You can also use [micro collections](http://docs.phalconphp.com/pt/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Micro_Collection.html) that allow the grouping of handlers.

```
$app->get('/me', 'userView');
$app->get('/users/{user_id}', 'userView');
```

Comment: Nice I'll give it a try.